# how to fill area between lines in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pulp

I want to fill the maximized area in from the below equation after plotting in matplotlib
Tried all possibilities but could not fill the desired area.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = np.linspace(0, 100, 2000)

# 3A+4B≤30

y1 = (30 - A * 3 ) /4
# 5A+6B≤60
y2 = (60 - A * 5)/6
# 1.5A+3B≤21
y3 = (21 - A * 1.5)/3.0

plt.plot(A, y1, label=r'$3A+4B\leq30$')
plt.plot(A, y2, label=r'$5A+6B\leq60$')
plt.plot(A, y3, label=r'$1.5A+3B\leq21$')


plt.xlim((0, 20))
plt.ylim((0, 15))
plt.xlabel(r'$x values$')
plt.ylabel(r'$y values$')

plt.fill_between(A, y3, where = y2<y3,color='grey', alpha=0.5)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(.80, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.1)
plt.show()
```

want to fill the area of maxim which is x = 2.0 and y = 6.0

Comment: What do you mean by the "maximised" area?

Comment: maximised area is the which gives the max through put.

Comment: And where is that on the graph?

Comment: Run the script given, you will see blue and green line intersecting. the area below these two lines(x and y plane).

Comment: You should just shade it in Paint or something so others will know exactly which area you're talking about.

Comment: @gmds not sure how to attach images to the questions/answers. I have added the code below. This is what i am expecting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one solution based on [this](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Matplotlib_SigmoidalFunctions.html) link. The only difference from the linked solution is that for your case, I had to use `fill_betweenx` to cover the whole x-axis common to the curves and switch the order of `x` and `Y`. The idea is to first find the intersection point within some tolerance and then take the values from one curve lying left to the point and the other curve lying right to the intersection. I also had to add an additional `[0]` in the `ind` to get it working

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = np.linspace(0, 100, 2000)

y1 = (30 - A * 3 ) /4
y2 = (60 - A * 5)/6
y3 = (21 - A * 1.5)/3.0

plt.plot(A, y1, label=r'$3A+4B\leq30$')
plt.plot(A, y2, label=r'$5A+6B\leq60$')
plt.plot(A, y3, label=r'$1.5A+3B\leq21$')

plt.xlim((0, 20))
plt.ylim((0, 12))
plt.xlabel(r'$x values$')
plt.ylabel(r'$y values$')

plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(.65, 0.95), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.1)

def fill_below_intersection(x, S, Z):
    """
    fill the region below the intersection of S and Z
    """
    #find the intersection point
    ind = np.nonzero( np.absolute(S-Z)==min(np.absolute(S-Z)))[0][0]
    # compute a new curve which we will fill below
    Y = np.zeros(S.shape)
    Y[:ind] = S[:ind]  # Y is S up to the intersection
    Y[ind:] = Z[ind:]  # and Z beyond it
    plt.fill_betweenx(Y, x, facecolor='gray', alpha=0.5) # <--- Important line

fill_below_intersection(A, y3, y1)
```

[image]

Comment: **You are a champ!** This is exactly what i was looking for. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to fill the area between `y1` and `y3` until they intersect with each other, because you specified (2, 6) as a point? Then use:

```py
plt.fill_between(A, y1, y3, where = y1<y3)
```

Analogously replace `y3` for `y2` if you meant the other curve. "Maximized area" is a bit misleading, as @gmds already commented.

Comment: i replaced y3 for y2 and vice versa.. this is not the output what i am looking for.

Comment: @VijayaBhaskar Then, perhaps you should specify what the output you are looking for is exactly.

Comment: @VijayaBhaskar there is no way telling what you want to achieve. If you want to fill everything below the green line until the intersection (not only between blue and green), then use `plt.fill_between(A, y3, where = y1<y3)`. Make sure to read [the docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html), then you should be able to easily resovle this yourself.

Comment: plt.fill_between(A,y3,where = y3<y1,color='grey', alpha=0.5)
plt.fill_between(A,y1,where = y1<y3,color='grey', alpha=0.5)
This is the code i replaced with the line plt.fill_between(A, y3, where = y2<y3,color='grey', alpha=0.5) and got the output. However not convinced as there is a overlap. I am looking for a single piece of code